# Not able to connect to spring boot websocket example from command line tools

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I have just cloned the [spring boot examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-websocket-tomcat) and run the tomcat websocket example without any change. After the server started I can not connect to the echo endpoint using any of the commandline tools like:

- [wscat](https://github.com/websockets/wscat) -c ws://localhost:8080/ws/echo/websocket -> Unexpected server response: 404
- [ws](https://github.com/hashrocket/ws) ws://localhost:8080/ws/echo/websocket -> bad handshake

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you connect from browser (i.e. `var q = new WebSocket("ws://...");` from developer console)? Also I've made another websocket tool: [websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat).

Comment: @websocat actually I am not using websocket anymore but sse and flux. and I am very happy with this solution, to me it's much more straight forward as the whole ws stack.